# Grouping in GraphQL query

Tags: api, graphql, graphql-ruby

I am new to GraphQl and learning it. Currently I have single database Table - `student_courses` as shown below:

```
student_id|   student_name   | course_code | course_name
1              ABC                S-101       DataStructures
1              ABC                S-150       NLP
1              ABC                S-250       Machine learning
2              PQR                S-101       DataStructures
3              XYZ                S-101       DataStructures
3              XYZ                S-150       NLP
```

I have mapped the model to single GraphQL object. So I am getting GraphQL API response as individual json objects for each row in table.

I wanted to understand how to group the results of this table by `student_id, student_name` and get results in below format:

`student_id, student_name, {course_code : course_name}`

For eg: `1, "ABC", {"S-101":"DataStructures", "S-150":"NLP", "S-250":"Machine learning"}`

My current GraphQL query -

```
{
  student_courses() {
    data {
      student_id
      student_name
      course_code
      course_name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: not query responsibility - resolver role

Comment: Ok, it will be great if you can point me to some good reference implementation on GraphQL resolver to implement this. Thanks!

Comment: IDK ruby, follow some tutorials about ORMs and graphql server in ruby/rails

Comment: Here's an answer that's worth a look. Clear explanation, useful examples and a code sandbox, not to mention a very kind response to someone wanting to learn. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27163#issuecomment-701222898

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to answer with the little you say about your database and about your backend: graphql is not intelligent about the data.

### Some reminders first:

To serve a GraphQL api you need a "**graphql backend**" you may be using a framework like [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/graphql), [apollo server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/), or if your database is a PostgreSql I recommend [postgraphile](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/).

These framework receive and parse Graphql queries, and "resolve" every sub part of a query with a function called a "resolver".
They may also help you connect to the database and generate part of the code that you need to get the data.

For example if you have a query like this:

```
      average {
        points
      }
```

You need a resolver to get you the "average" field, and another resolver to get the "points" sub field of the "average" object.

#### Back to your question

Grouping results would be something that you code in your resolver, the graphql engine would not "know" how to ask your database to make a join or a group query.

On postgraphile you can use the [pg-aggregates plugin](https://github.com/graphile/pg-aggregates) that can do this for you (because it is specialized on binding itself with postgresql database).

You would be able to resolve Graphql queries like this.

```
query GroupedAggregatesByDerivative {
  allMatchStats {
    byDay: groupedAggregates(groupBy: [CREATED_AT_TRUNCATED_TO_DAY]) {
      keys # The timestamp truncated to the beginning of the day
      average {
        points
      }
    }
    byHour: groupedAggregates(groupBy: [CREATED_AT_TRUNCATED_TO_HOUR]) {
      keys # The timestamp truncated to the beginning of the hour
      average {
        points
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In practise that will mean that your resolver will take a parameter called "groupBy" and depending on its value return different data.

Remark: on the Graphql schema side the `allMatchStats` query will have to be modified so that it takes the `byDay` field as input and its output will not be a "`match`" but another custom defined type that contains the `average` field for example. (note that on the case above the postgraphile plugin, generates all this for you)